# Can dgraph be used to model a street network?

Tags: routes, geospatial, openstreetmap, graph-databases, dgraph

is [dgraph](https://dgraph.io/) appropriate to model real world maps (street maps, indoor maps)?
Let's assume you took complete Europe as map and model it as a dgraph. Then do tasks like route calculation, spatial queries ... .
Will it perform well or will another data base outperform?

Thanks.

Comment: Let us assume you want to do some routing algorithms, then you can just try it and compare to more specialized storages used in OSRM or GraphHopper (I'm one of the authors). Also have a look into Neo4J.

Comment: I'm aware of other databases but actually I'd like to know how they compare in terms of efficiency for routing algorithms for street networks.

Comment: The more specialized the faster. From my experience neo4j was using at least 5 times the RAM and CPU compared to GraphHopper. And we speak here of normal Dijkstra algorithm, with specialized algos the difference can be easily multiplied by 50 or 100.

Comment: What is the reason for this? Is it caused by java (dgraph may not have this overhead) or is the reason the graphdatabase?

Comment: GraphHopper is in Java too, so routing engines are just highly specialized and a graph database has to be more generic in several places

Answer (score 3):

Author of Dgraph here.

Dgraph supports geospatial index natively. That was built very early on into Dgraph. We're using similar techniques to what is used internally at Google.

It also supports k-shortest path calculations. So, yes, you could model Europe as a map, put it into Dgraph, and find [nearest restaurants], or [path from Paris to Berlin], etc. Dgraph is designed to run these use cases efficiently.

Comment: Hello Manish, is there a tutorial available for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can most certainly import OpenStreetMap open data into Dgraph using the [bulk loader](https://docs.dgraph.io/deploy/#fast-data-loading) for the initial data loading. There are functions you will make a lot of use of such as [geolocation-specific functions](https://docs.dgraph.io/query-language/#geolocation) and [path queries](https://docs.dgraph.io/query-language/#k-shortest-path-queries).

I use these extensively with a graph representation of topics and terms and they are very efficient. Now, even with all of this being said, you will have to make data model design choices, *e.g. favorite edges over intermediary nodes to model relationships.*